# file upload With Process bar using Iframe for IE

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, file-upload

I wrote the code to upload a file for IE Using Iframe  To Do it Work .
Just upload is done .  But I want a **processbar** But I do not know what to do Please, please help.

```
       function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
            // Create the iframe...
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
            iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
            iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");
            //target = "#fileIframe"
            // Add to document...
            form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
            window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";

            iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");

            // Add event...
            var eventHandler = function () {

                if (iframeId.detachEvent) {
                    iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);
    //                $('#progressNumber').text("100%");
                }
                else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);
                //            if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.removeEventListener("progress", uploadProgress1, false);
                // Message from server...
                if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                    content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.document) {
                    content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
                }

                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;

                // Del the iframe...
                setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);
            }

            if (iframeId.addEventListener) {
                iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
              //  $('#progressNumber').text("Processing...");
            }
            if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);

            // Set properties of form...
            form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
            form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
            // Submit the form...
            form.submit();

            document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";
        }
        function fileSelectedIE() {
            var fullname = $('#fileToUpload').val().toString();
            var IndexExt = fullname.lastIndexOf(".");
            var ext = fullname.substr(IndexExt + 1).toString();
            var IndexFileName = fullname.lastIndexOf("\\");
            var FileName = fullname.substring(IndexFileName+1, IndexExt).toString();
            document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = 'Name: ' + FileName;
            document.getElementById('fileSize').innerHTML = 'Size: Not Support';
            document.getElementById('fileType').innerHTML = 'Type: ' + ext;
        }
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" onchange="fileSelectedIE()" /></br>


    <input type="button" value="upload" onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'UploadHandler.ashx','upload'); return false;"/>
 <div id="fileName">
    </div>
    <div id="fileSize">
    </div>
    <div id="fileType">
    </div>
    <div id="progressNumber">
    </div>
```

How do create process bar when uploading file?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to track file upload progress in user agents that support the File API.  Unfortunately, IE9 and earlier do not.  You will not be able to (easily) track file upload progress without File API support.  It is, theoretically, possible via an FileUpload module for nginx or apache.  This is detailed more in [a feature request](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/506) for a javascript uploader I maintain.